# How to use * or ? character in batch file during update of a text file using repl.bat?

Tags: batch-file, batch-rename

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "search=jre1.8.0_?"
set "replace=jre1.8.0_156"
set "textfile=C:\Program Files\ABC\_ABC_installation\Uninstall_ABC.lax"
set "newfile=C:\Program Files\ABC\_ABC_installation\Uninstall_ABC1.lax"
pause;
call repl.bat "%search%" "%replace%" L < "%textfile%" >"%newfile%"
pause;
del "%textfile%"
rename "%newfile%" "%textfile%"
pause;
```

The batch file should match anything like `jre1.8.0_121` or `jre1.8.0_152`.

So I want to replace `jre1.8.0_?` with `jre1.8.0_156`, but neither `?` nor `*` works on replace.

The replace works fine on removing this wildcard character.

Comment: You are using a deprecated version of `REPL`.  A new version was put out 3 years ago and renamed as [JREPL](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044). You can ask your question on the DosTips forum as well. That is where the code is maintained as of now.

Comment: [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecated `repl.bat` as well as [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) use JScript which offers regular expression support.

In ECMAScript/JavaScript/JScript/Perl regular expression syntax `\d+` or `[0-9]+` matches 1 or more digits, i.e. a positive integer number.

So the command line to use in the batch file is one of those 2 lines on using `jrepl.bat`:

```
call jrepl.bat "jre1\.8\.0_\d+" "jre1.8.0_156" /F "%ProgramFiles%\ABC\_ABC_installation\Uninstall_ABC.lax" /O -
call jrepl.bat "jre1\.8\.0_[0-9]+" "jre1.8.0_156" /F "%ProgramFiles%\ABC\_ABC_installation\Uninstall_ABC.lax" /O -
```

Or use one of those two lines on still using `repl.bat`.

```
set "search=jre1\.8\.0_\d+"
set "search=jre1\.8\.0_[0-9]+"
```

The `.` has a special meaning in a regular expression search string. It means by default any character except newline characters (according to Unicode standard). To get `.` interpreted as literal character, it must be escaped with a backslash.

The option `L` must be removed on usage of `repl.bat` as the search string is not anymore a string to find literally, but a regular expression string.

The batch code using deprecated `repl.bat` can't work as long as input and output file have same name. And even on using for output file a different name, the posted batch code does not work because command **rename**  requires that the new file name is specified without path.
The command **move** can be used to replace input file by modified output file.

The entire batch code really working using deprecated `repl.bat`.

```
@echo off & setlocal
set "search=jre1\.8\.0_\d+"
set "replace=jre1.8.0_156"
set "textfile=%ProgramFiles%\ABC\_ABC_installation\Uninstall_ABC.lax"
set "newfile=%ProgramFiles%\ABC\_ABC_installation\Uninstall_ABC.tmp"
call repl.bat "%search%" "%replace%" <"%textfile%" >"%newfile%"
move /Y "%newfile%" "%textfile%"
```

Hint: Do not use a semicolon after command `pause`. There is absolute no need for a semicolon. The semicolon after `pause` just tests the error correction handling of Windows command interpreter.